# How to ignore a method if method is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I am new to ruby on rails and can't really write methods yet....

I am getting an error when uploading an image which doesn't contain exif data.

I need this method to allow for both imgfile and imgfile.nil. How would I either define a default value or ignore this code if imfile.nil?

```
# Image geolocation
def get_image_loc
imgfile = EXIFR::JPEG.new(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
return unless imgfile

lat = imgfile.exif[0].gps_latitude[0].to_f + (imgfile.exif[0].gps_latitude[1].to_f / 60) + (imgfile.exif[0].gps_latitude[2].to_f / 3600)
lng = imgfile.exif[0].gps_longitude[0].to_f + (imgfile.exif[0].gps_longitude[1].to_f / 60) + (imgfile.exif[0].gps_longitude[2].to_f / 3600)

lat = lat * -1 if imgfile.exif[0].gps_latitude_ref == "S"      # (N is +, S is -)
lng = lng * -1 if imgfile.exif[0].gps_longitude_ref == "W"   # (W is -, E is +)

self.img_loc_lat  = lat # imgfile.gps_latitude
self.img_loc_lng  = lng # imgfile.gps_longitude
end

end
```

here is the part which calls this method in my show.erb file

```
<% unless @pin.img_loc_lat.blank?
            # bespoke code to load a map if the location information is available 
            # Google Static Maps for now
            # Look to upgrade to Google Maps API 3 - there seem to be a few gems available for it
        %>
            <p>&nbsp;<br />
                <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<%= @pin.img_loc_lat %>,<%= @pin.img_loc_lng %>&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green%7Clabel:P%7C<%= @pin.img_loc_lat %>,<%= @pin.img_loc_lng %>&sensor=false">
            </p>
        <% end %>
```

My git

https://github.com/nathan-wallace/dcphotogrid-app.git

Comment: `return unless imgfile && imgfile.exif && !imgfile.exif.empty?` ?

Comment: this allows me to post images without exif data but I still get an error when uploading an image with exif data

Answer (score 0):

You can check if img_loc_lat is nil:

```
<% unless @pin.img_loc_lat.nil? %>
```

If there is a possiblity of `img_loc_lat` being a string or nil, you can also convert it to a string and check if it's empty:

```
<% unless @pin.img_loc_lat.to_s.empty? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the html block as a helper and then call it as a method with .try()

```
@instance.try(:method_name)
```

if @instance is blank then the method won't be called.